# Error while downloading Lists in a spweb

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

Here is the code

```
private void downloadList(SPObjectData objectData)
    {
        using (SPWeb currentWeb = objectData.Web)
        {
            foreach (SPList list in currentWeb.Lists)
            {
                    foreach (SPFolder oFolder in list.Folders)
                    {
                        if (oFolder != null)
                        {
                            foreach (SPFile file in oFolder.files)
                            {
                                if (CreateDirectoryStructure(tbDirectory.Text, file.Url))
                                {
                                    var filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(tbDirectory.Text, file.Url);
                                    byte[] binFile = file.OpenBinary();
                                    System.IO.FileStream fstream = System.IO.File.Create(filepath);
                                    fstream.Write(binFile, 0, binFile.Length);
                                    fstream.Close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Error while compilation

> Error Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder'.

Error coming on line " foreach (SPFolder oFolder in list.Folders)

I am trying to assign a folder in list. folders to folder but for some reason it giving error mentioned above.

I was trying to get folders from a Lists but after reading difference between folder and list objects on link given below, i changed my code as mentioned below, cheers

[enter link description here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepointdevelopment/thread/03e11ce4-fb38-4d2e-925a-8d5c06f16459)

```
private void downloadList(SPObjectData objectData)
    {
        using (SPWeb currentWeb = objectData.Web)
        {
            foreach (SPFolder oFolder in currentWeb.Folders)
            {
                if (oFolder != null)
                {
                    foreach (SPFile file in oFolder.Files)
                    {
                        if (CreateDirectoryStructure(tbDirectory.Text, file.Url))
                        {
                            var filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(tbDirectory.Text, file.Url);
                            byte[] binFile = file.OpenBinary();
                            System.IO.FileStream fstream = System.IO.File.Create(filepath);
                            fstream.Write(binFile, 0, binFile.Length);
                            fstream.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nothing coming on Google

Comment: You probably should have accepted the answer below, as it fixed your original question, then created a new question with the new problem. Now the answer below, which was correct, no longer matches your question.

Comment: true said, but code wasn't right so I had to change the question so if somone else uses it , shouldn't get confused, anyway I selected the answer plus posting the right code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
foreach (SPFile file in oFolder.Files)
```

Update: If there is a problem just index into it:

```
SPFileCollection collFiles = oFolder.Files;

        long lngTotalFileSize = 0;

        for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < collFiles.Count; intIndex++)
        {
            lngTotalFileSize += collFiles[intIndex].Length;
        }
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks lot, i think am bit sleepy this evening ! :)

Comment: hehe its actually morning for me. :-)

Comment: another error's there wonder why its not talking folder from list.folders :/

Comment: my first error has been solved , now its a different problem :(